# Marketing cloud - update subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, update

I have over 100,000 records in a subscribers list. Each of these records have a first name, last name, email address, and zip code field. I need to add a new field called "state" populate it with the name of the state that matches the zip code.  Does the Marketing Cloud platform have anything that can support this? If not, any recommendations on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing that'll in SFMC that'll match states from zip codes.

My recommendation would be to:

1. Add a new Profile Attribute called "State"
2. Export your All Subscribers to a tab-delimited file
3. Open the file in Excel and populate the State column with a source data [vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) (a few sources are noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894104/free-city-state-zipcode-to-latitude-longitude-database))
4. Save it as a tab-delimited file
5. Import the file into All Subscribers as an Update